# Index of the community from iGraph community algorithms

Tags: igraph

Does the index of the community from any of the iGraph community algorithms have a meaning? e.g., if I use fc <- fastgreedy.community(g) and I get communities 1,2,3: does community 1 mean it was the strongest community because it merged first in the algorithm or are they just labels?

Comment: I looked up the original [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0408187) that is behind `fastgreedy.community(g)` and there's nothing there to suggest that there is an inherent ordering to the communities returned by it. What exactly do you mean by *strongest* communinty anyway?

Comment: Strongest defined as those communities that emerged the fastest (because the algorithm greedily merges groups that increase Q) so thought maybe they labeled them accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ordering; the community IDs that igraph uses are only arbitrary numbers.